# Modifying django's default "_id" suffix for related objects

Tags: python, django

I am integrating django with a legacy system and database and have a model that looks like this

```
class Label(models.Model)
    iLabelID = models.IntegerField(db_column='LABELID', primary_key=True)
    organization = models.OneToOneField(Organization, related_name='labels', db_column='ORGANIZATION')
    sLabelText = models.CharField(max_length=42)
```

Using this notation (more or less [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)) is a requirement of the project.

The following will work in django:

```
>>> Label.objects.get(organization_id=1)
```

But I want to be able to write this:

```
>>> Label.objects.get(iOrganizationID=1)
```

I tried subclassing models.OneToOneField with

```
class MyOneToOneField(models.OneToOneField):
    def get_attname(self):
        # default is:
        # return '%s_id' % self.name
        return 'i%s%sID' % (self.name[0].upper(), self.name[1:])
```

But this is the error I get when trying to use it:

```
>>> Label.objects.get(iOrganizationID=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 230, in iterator
    obj = model(*row_data)
  File "django/db/models/base.py", line 347, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.attname, val)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

EDIT: here's another pain point:

I wish to generate some JSON. This JSON will be fed to another part of the system on which I have no control (not possible to change names). I wish I could do the following:

```
json.dumps(list(Label.objects.values('iLabelID', 'iOrganizationID', 'sAnotherValue')))
```

But this is not possible. I have to do this

```
list(Label.objects.values('iLabelID', 'organization_id', 'sAnotherValue'))
```

And then manually map `organization_id` to `iOrganizationID`, although this is not a problem for the label's ID. It makes code more difficult to maintain, to read, and slower to execute.

Note that this is *not* specific to hungarian notation, you may need to suffix with `_identifier` or `_pk` or whatever instead of `_id`.

EDIT2: I must have made another error because as lanzz pointed out get_attname does work -_-

Comment: You have neither a model field nor a database column named "iOrganizationID"; how exactly do you imagine Django would rewrite your filter into a query? If your model field had `db_column='iOrganizationID'`, your filter would have worked.

Comment: It doesn't have a column named 'organization_id' either...

Comment: Apparently the `foreignkeyfield_id=...` filtering is special-cased in Django and doesn't actually reference the true `db_column` name of the field; getting what you want might be much trickier than initially anticipated.

Comment: Yes, and from reading django's code, this magical '_id' suffix seems to come from ForeignKey's get_attname method. But there must be other bits elsewhere since simply overriding get_attname didn't work.

Comment: A more general comment: You are writing *Using this notation (more or less hungarian notation) is a requirement of the project*. You **have to** reconsider this. Django has a specific, similar to PEP 8, coding style: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/. I really can't understand why there is a requirement on the coding style! Please talk to your managers and try to convince them to use the django coding style. Tell us how did it go :)

Comment: Hehe, I've already tried in the past ;-) The sad part is that I'm starting to see advantages to it. Especially since the python code deals mostly with JSON data where there is only a few basic types, you can in a glimpse of an eye see if something went wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why you haven't called the field `iOrganizationID` if you want to query using that name.

Comment: Because the field name is used for a special instance that is not an id. With your suggestion I could be doing `mylabel.iOrganizationID.sOrganizationName`. That's why `_id` is automagically added: it doesn't make sense to call the field `organization_id`.

Comment: Well if you ask me, *none* of this makes sense. You're saying that you want to special-case the lookup by ID, but keep the field as "organization" and the db column as "ORGANIZATION"?

Comment: @Rems "The sad part is that I'm starting to see advantages to it." That's the stockholm syndrome kicking in. Resist it.

Comment: From Microsoft's "General naming conventions" : "*DO NOT* use Hungarian notation." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).

Comment: No need to try to convince me not to use hungarian notation, it doesn't solve my problem. And the problem is not specific to hungarian notation (I changed the title, it was misleading). The "_id" suffix is not a PEP8 standard, and is not a standard at all. In Django, you can customize field names, related names, verbose names, etc.... Why not give me the ability to customize how a name is "identifier-ified"?

Comment: I have tested your solution with the overridden `get_attname()` method, and it works fine — I could not reproduce your `can't set attribute` situation, and saving and filtering using the overridden attribute name works as expected. You should look for the cause of the `can't set attribute` error elsewhere — the `.get_attname()` approach works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using some modifications of your code:

```
class CustomAttrNameForeignKey(djangoFields.related.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        attname = kwargs.pop('attrname', None)
        super(CustomAttrNameForeignKey, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.attname = attname or super(CustomAttrNameForeignKey, self).get_attname()

    def get_attname(self):
        return self.attname
```

---

```
class AModelUsingThis(djangoModels.Model):
    snapshot = CustomAttrNameForeignKey(
            ParentalModel, db_column="timestamp", to_field="timestamp",
            attrname='timestamp', related_name="children")
```

In this case we get in the model an attribute for FK with no suffix at all, but with the name given. I haven't tested it yet on DB, but just tried to instantiate model also with this custom FK given -- it works fine.