# Django OneToOneField relation with to_field and db_column been ignored on makemigrations files

Tags: python, django, models

Even after reading the docs on [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column) and [Django' recomendations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) I was not able to accomplish the desired results with this feature.

This is part of my code

```
class DefaultBaseModel(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(primary_key=True, 
                            unique=True, 
                            null=False, 
                            blank=False)

class Bill(DefaultBaseModel):

class Payment(DefaultBaseModel):
    bill = models.OneToOneField(Bill, 
                                related_name='payments', 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                to_field='slug', 
                                db_column='bill_slug')
```

What I expect to do is the following on Django's shell:

```
from apps.bills.models import Payment
p = Payment.objects.first()
p.bill_slug
```

However I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Payment' object has no attribute 'bill_slug'
```

Well,

```
p.bill_id
```

gives me the slug value but it is still creating the column with the suffix _id.

- I tried to delete makemigrations (migrate) files (those initial.py and others) and create it again
- Moved from Sqlite to Postgres
- Looked into Django's makemigrations files and db_column='bill_slug' was there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a slug as a primary key? It's not very efficient.  Just get rid of the `primary_key=True,` in the slug field. That's where the `_id` is coming from.

Comment: Hello there. I appreciate your concern with the efficiency of the modeling. I have done as you suggested, nevertheless the results were the same plus a one more field on database, the id.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything called "branch_slug" is there? A `Bill` has a `slug` though. In your example code, I don't see `branch` anywhere. Try to be less verbose with column and table names and see if it's working:

```
class DefaultBaseModel(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Bill(DefaultBaseModel):

class Payment(DefaultBaseModel):
    bill = models.OneToOneField(Bill, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

Now this should work:

```
from apps.bills.models import Bill, Payment
b = Bill.objects.first()
b.slug

p = Payment.objects.first()
p.bill.slug
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes in my question. I have edited it. I tried to be less verbose and things worked like you said in this case.

Comment: My mistake was that I was looking and showing wrong fields in my question and, you are right, there was not "branch_slug". But I edited and I think there should be a "bill_slug" when I query for Payment.

Comment: The `db_column` declaration only applies to the database. The name of the `field` is still "slug". So to access it from python you will need to use `p.bill.slug`.

Comment: But how would you explain the fact that I can type `p.bill_id` and it gives me the slug and I can not change the name `bill_id` into `bill_slug`

Comment: That's the way it would work as you originally designed it. Have you run migrations so the DB gets the model changes?

Comment: Yes, I have run it. Unfortunately it did not change database fields.

Comment: Well then I can't explain it. I'm not sure what DB you're running. You could look at the table configuration. Though you could try this: Delete the `slug` field, then run migrations and migrate, then add the `slug` field back. That should fix it.

Comment: But you helped a lot. I have gone on **postgres** via _psql_ typed `\d+ bills_payment` and the column `bill_slug` was there on `public.bills_payment` as it should be. However, on Django's shell when I `dir` a _PaymentQuerySet_ it is still show bill_id. It narrowed down where I can find the causes of it. Thank you.

Comment: For now I am trying this kind of [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524830/modifying-djangos-default-id-suffix-for-related-objects) and this code: `for field in Bill._meta.fields:` 
`field.get_attname_column()` helped me get a better view of whats was going on.